# Can I make the terminal wrap lines without splitting words?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to make the terminal wrap lines without splitting the line in the middle of a word, but rather splitting the line a bit earlier to avoid doing that. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can wrap _text_ with `fold`, but that's not your interactive terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. The terminal displays characters, and does not care about grammar and words. If all characters on a line are used, it moves on to the next line.

If you copy the line to a text editor, you will be fine: no returns are inserted in the output. If you resize the terminal, the characters will adapt along.